# How to fill in an area below detected contours in Python OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I am looking to fill the area under a boundary with white color. I basically have an image with the red boundary detected through the `findContours` method

[image]

I am now looking at filling the area below this detected red boundary with white color. This would allow me to distinguish between the area below the red boundary and the area above for a histogram computation.
Can someone help me with this? Open to suggestions outside OpenCV as well, if it's easier to implement.

Comment: What do you mean as "below"? There are some closed boundaries and a lot of ripples.

Answer (score 0):

You are drawing after findContours operation. you can get the points(x,y) you are painting and you can calculate it with a simple row to column ratio.

Comment: Thanks. I can get the contour points being traced out, but I'm unsure how I can use that to fill in the image below the boundary with a specific color. Is there a function that can use for this?